# Вызов php функций из отдельного файла.

Tags: php, функции

Есть куча php функций, которые используются на разных страницах. Я их собрал в отдельный файл и в необходимых местах подключал includ'ом. Можно ли как-то обойтись без инклуда? Наподобии java скриптов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Разбейте функции на несколько файлов, а лучше еще оберните в классы

2) Включайте их по мере надобности через require_once

Как вариант для ускорения можно использовать свой список подключенных файлов (require_once рекомендуют использовать в крайних случаях, ибо медленная)

```
function incfile($f) {
  if (!isset($_ENV['included'])) $_ENV['included'] = array();
  if (!empty($_ENV['included'][$f])) return true;
  require $f;
  $_ENV['included'][$f] = 1;
  return true;
  }
incfile('class.my-text-utility.php');
incfile('class.my-image-utility.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Разве что посылать гет или пост запросы, а в файле с функциями обрабатывать их.
Но это глупо.. чем инклуд то не угодил?

Comment: В файле КУЧА функций. Не все из них используются на каждой странице. Как библиотека получается. Если каждый раз инклудить, то две трети seyrwbq использоваться все-равно не будет. Это на производительности не сказывается? Если нет, то можно и инклудом обойтись...

Answer (score 0):

Если вам важен только результат выполнения той функции, то вариант от kenpachi подходит.
Как вариант использовать **require()**, дело в том, что эта функция независимо от своего положения в файле, подключает в самом начале нужный файл и тем самым работает в несколько раз быстрее **includ**'а.

Comment: И вы не правы.

    // t2.php
    <? echo ++$a.' '; ?>

    // t.php
    <? $a = 0; while ($a < 5) require 't1.php'; ?>

Результат: 1 2 3 4 5
<hr />
Скорость повышается за счет отсутствия проверок. Если **include** при неудаче возвращает *false*, **require** падает с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Оберните функции в классы, разбейте на отдельные классы функции. И почитайте про функцию - [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php).